# Error in installing tailwind css in react + vite

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, tailwind-css, vite

I have tried the below command to install the tailwind css but the following error occured. Help me to solve this problem -->

```
No fix available
PS C:\Users\Deepak Dhaka\OneDrive\Desktop\chai_aur_React\02tailwind> npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'amqplib@0.5.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=0.8 <=9' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v21.4.0', npm: '10.2.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

up to date, audited 477 packages in 1m

111 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

12 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 7 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Problem Description:
I'm encountering issues with package installations in my React.js project. Upon running npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer, I'm getting multiple warnings and vulnerabilities.

Comment: There does not seem to be any errors in the output you gave. The warnings are warnings. The packages should still operate normally.

Comment: could you share what issue you are facing when using tailwindcss classes?